# Multi Replace String in Javascript like PHP str_replace

Tags: javascript

in php we can replace multiple string with array
like this

```
$cleanbase64 = base64_decode(str_replace(array('-', '_',' ','\n'), array('+', '/','+',' '), $base64file));
```

but how to implement that to javascript ,  i tried like this

```
const cleanbase64 = base64file.replace(/\-/, "+").replace(/_/, "/").replace(/ /, "+").replace(/\n/, " ");
const buffer = Buffer.from(cleanbase64, 'base64');
```

but the base64 seems broken , and i can't convert into image

Comment: use replaceAll() with regex

Comment: [The documentation for `replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.